# Python: Why is entry set to the value of 1

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and I am trying to figure out why the value of `entry` in the following code is set to "1" at the top of the code, and why when I press "0" as the first and only digit when testing the code the "sum" gets to be "0" and not "1" when the "entry" is already bound up with number of “1”.
Also, what is `entry` called? A function?
Best regards

```
entry = 1
total = 0
while entry > 0:
    entry = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    total += entry
print('The sum of all numbers =', total)
```

Comment: `total` is initialised to 0, and entry is overwritten by `input` before it is added the first time - the initial value of `1` is only required to pass the test in `while`. `entry` is called a variable or name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entry` is a variable.

It has been set to 1 to enter into the `while loop`. For while loop to run you need condition to be `True`. So it evaluates `1 > 0` which is `True` and enters into the loop.

As value of `entry` is overriden in while loop, it takes the value from user input.
As you said if you press 0 the value of entry will become 0 instead of 1 and the will get added to `sum` which is 0 so `0+0` will return 0.

You can set it to any value greater than Zero.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Here `Entry` is basically used as a flag, which is set to `True` so that the `While` loop can run continuously untill 0(zero) is passed as a `False` value for `Entry` variable, which i turns than stops the `While` loop and return Total Sum.

Answer (score 0):

`entry` is variable. It is 1 after `entry = 1`. So first time inside `while` loop `entry > 0` is true and you go inside loop and read one number, and assign it to entry. Now if you enter `0` then `entry` is 0, and 0+0 is 0, so `total` is 0, and `entry > 0` is false, so you fall out of `while` loop and print: "The sum of all numbers =0`.

But but but: question "**why** is entry set to value of 1" I cannot answer. You must go ask person who wrote this code and ask, "why is entry set to value of 1?" and maybe then you get answer. But I cannot give you that answer.

To me it looks like silly code written for silly reasons. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The initial value of `entry` is set 1 and on the other hand you are also taking `input` with the same variable. So, whenever you are putting 0 on it the `entry` variable becoming 0 as initial value.
`total` is already set as 0 and it add the `entry` value which is also 0 so the result become 0.
So when the `loop` goes back & check its condition `entry > 0 becoming 0 > 0` which is false.

so the code does something like this,

> You Code

```
entry = 1
total = 0
while entry > 0:
    entry = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    total += entry
print('The sum of all numbers =', total)
```

> First Attempt

```
entry = 1
total = 0
while entry > 0: # 1 > 0 because entry = 1
    entry = int(input('Enter a number: ')) # entry is becoming 0
    total += entry # total = 0, because entry is 0 now
print('The sum of all numbers =', total)
```

> Last Attempt

```
entry = 1
total = 0
while entry > 0: # 0 > 0 False because entry = 0
    entry = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    total += entry
print('The sum of all numbers =', total)
```

> Output

`>>> The sum of all numbers = 0`